# Getting facebook data since a specific post ~[({python})]~

Tags: python, facebook, api

I am trying to retrieve all facebook posts by a user after a post id. When I do it, I get an unknown error.

my code:

```
from facebook import *
token = facebook.get_app_access_token('3291XXXXXXXXXXXXX','c498e60cb1eXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
graph = GraphAPI(token)
g = graph.get('travelguard/posts?limit=5&since=68827688457_10151569356908458')

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    graph.get('travelguard/posts?limit=5&since=68827688457_10151569356908458')
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 42, in get
    retry=retry
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 251, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 251, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 251, in _query
    return self._query(method, path, data, page, retry - 1)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 248, in _query
    return load(method, url, data)[0]
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 210, in load
    result = self._parse(response.content)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\visolank\Desktop\Python\programs\facepy\graph_api.py", line 290, in _parse
    error.get('code', None)
OAuthError: [1] An unknown error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook's API doesn't have the best error messages. "An unknown error has occurred." means you don't have permissions to access what you're trying to access.